# ggplot2 renaming y axis using external variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

As part of shiny command, suppose I wish to rename (censor) the non-chosen names on ggplot *without changing the data itself*, i.e., via + ggplot command.

(Nothing that stops me from changing data, but I just wanted to know if it is possible with only ggplot)

The user can define which name can be kept.

The user does not know the possible names that appear in the plot.

The names to be kept may not even appear in the plot at all, and result in the plot with all censored name.

```
library(ggplot2)

#user can change this variable
keepname <- c("Valiant", "Honda Civic", "AMC Javelin")

#user may not alter the ggplot lines.
ggplot(head(mtcars,10),aes(x=factor(vs),y=rownames(head(mtcars,10)),fill=gear)) +
  geom_tile(color="gray60")
  scale_y_discrete(labels= #something here using `keepname`#)
```

[image]

The resulting plot should be all y-axis except "Valiant" be renamed, like in `LETTERS` for this example.

The possible y axis for different ggplot is different, so I cannot explicitly write `scale_y_discrete(labels=c("Merc 230"="X"))`.

The length of `keepname` can vary also, but never will be more than 10, so I believe something can be done using `censorname <- LETTERS[length(keepname)]` for renaming.

Answer (score 0):

```
kcheck <- function(x){
  return(
    ifelse(x %in% keepname, x, NA)
  )
}


test.plot +
  scale_y_discrete(labels=kcheck)
```

Worked, although it will change everything to NA and unable to codify individual cars into different `LETTERS`.